# ComboBox Items Empty but DataSource Full

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

After binding a list to combobox, its dataSource.Count is 5 but, combobox item count is 0.
how can it be?

I'm used to Web programming and this is in Windows Forms.
So no `combo.DataBind();` method exists.

The problem here is, I'm trying to set the selected item programmatically. Since I don't see the combo.Items collection filled, I cannot set the desired item.

---

***Update***

A total update is needed I guess:

- datasource contains 7 items
- when bound to combobox, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are appropriately implemented
- after databound, through the gui, I can clearly see the 7 items in the combobox
- `combobox.DataSource.Count = 7` and `combobox.Items.Count = 0`

So the problem is here; since after databound no items are there in the ItemCollection of combobox; I cannot search for one to match and set the appropriate one.

Here is a image for better understanding (But I'm pretty sure I'm missing sth simple)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Had you set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` accordingly?

Comment: Or `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. What datatype is in DataSource?

Comment: Yes, maybe the question is not fully understandable. The databound event is successfully working, I can see my items in the combo through the gui. The problem is, in debug; after the datasource assignment the combobox does not contain something in the Items collection. Like after the render, all of the items are shown but before that nothing there.

Comment: In comboBox (windows form) there is no DataTextField and DataValueField properties. where you found these?

Comment: @AminulIslam I updated my vocabulary habit problem and updated the image incase you don't believe me. Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you create a BindingSource, set it's DataSource, and then just pass along the DataSource (instead of the BindingSource) to the ComboBox. What happens if you set the BindingSource object itself as the DataSource for the ComboBox?

Comment: @SPFiredrake the problem I questioned happens, and the reason I created a bindingSource is that I used the same source for multiple combobox instances and if I didn't create a bindingSource they act in the same way, like if I select something on one of them, everyone is set selected for that item.

Comment: When you create a new `BindingSource`, all the bindings happen independantly of where that same datasource is utilized. Even if you've bound the datasource to 4 other controls, if each one has it's own `BindingSource` instance, they each have their own internal `BindingContext` that handles state/position/events relating to that particular control. You just solved it by explicitly telling the ComboBox to use a new BindingContext instead of letting the BindingSource take care of it.

Comment: Crap, sorry, not an internal `BindingContext`, an internal `CurrencyManager`. Just took a look at the source. Either way, it should handle the events separately for each `BindingSource` that's used since it has it's own `CurrencyManager` (which again, handles state representation in the BindingSource itself for the specified DataSource, even if the DataSource is used elsewhere).

Comment: Didn't know the internals, thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After adding `ddl.BindingContext = new BindingContext();` before the `BindingSource` assignment, everything worked fine.

Comment: When using the datasource the first time everything works fine. As soon as you use the datasource a second time you need to also reuse the bindingcontext or create a new one like you did.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd expand DataSource items in debuger, you'd probably notice that 1st element on list is null. That is why DataSource does not render ComboBox Items. Removing null items from the list should do all the work;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case it was caused by calling

```
combobox.Sorted = True
```

in `InitializeComponent`.  I guess that call initializes `Items`, which then prevents the assignment to `DataSource` from updating it (`Items`).