# ComboBox DataSource Dynamically Change

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

First: I have **List** that filled up with object type of **Customer**

```
List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();
```

Second: I have 2 **ComboBox**, one for **Customer Name** and other for **Customer Phone**. And set both **DataSource** to **Customers** list.

```
CustomersPhone_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Phone).ToList();
CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Name).ToList();
```

Third: When the user change selected item in **Phone ComboBox**, I want to filter the names in **Name ComboBox** Which is have the same Phone number it was selected. **(Because it may be the phone number registered with more than one name)**. I have this code

```
private void CustomersPhone_ComBx_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CustomersPhone_ComBx.Text != "")
         CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Where(Customer => Customer.Phone == CustomersPhone_ComBx.Text).Select(Customer => Customer.Name).ToList();
    else
         CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Name).ToList();
}
```

But when I test it and change selected item in **Phone ComboBox** nothing change in **Name ComboBox**.

---

**Update 1**

Fourth: If I used `foreach`, it works fine like the following code, but don't work with **DataSource**

```
private void CustomersPhone_ComBx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Customer> FilteredCustomers = Customers
                       .Where(Customer => Customer.Phone == CustomersPhone_ComBx.Text).ToList();

    foreach (Customer C in FilteredCustomers)
        CustomersName_ComBx.Items.Add(C.Name);
}
```

---

**Update 2**

Theses properties of 2 ComboBox, they are the same.

```
        // CustomersName_ComBx
        // 
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Janna LT", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 65);
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 7, 0, 0);
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.Name = "CustomersName_ComBx";
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(583, 46);
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.Sorted = true;
        this.CustomersName_ComBx.TabIndex = 52;
        // 
        // CustomersPhone_ComBx
        // 
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Janna LT", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 7);
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 7, 0, 0);
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.Name = "CustomersPhone_ComBx";
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(583, 46);
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.Sorted = true;
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.TabIndex = 51;
        this.CustomersPhone_ComBx.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.CustomersPhone_ComBx_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

And the form named **NewReceipt_Delivery_Form** and these line how I show it.

```
NewReceipt_Delivery_Form NewReceipt_Delivery_Form = new NewReceipt_Delivery_Form();
NewReceipt_Delivery_Form.ChangeUI();
NewReceipt_Delivery_Form.ShowDialog();
```

And **ChangeUI** method

```
private List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();
public void ChangeUI()
{
    OleDbCommand SelectCustomersCMD = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY [ID] ASC", Program.GeneralConnection);
    OleDbDataReader SelectCustomersREAD = SelectCustomersCMD.ExecuteReader();
    while (SelectCustomersREAD.Read())
    {
        Customer Customer = new Customer();
        Customer.ID = Convert.ToInt32(SelectCustomersREAD[0].ToString());
        /* And so on. */
        Customers.Add(Customer);
    }
    SelectCustomersREAD.Close();
    CustomersPhone_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Phone).ToList();
    CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Name).ToList();
    CustomersPhone_ComBx.SelectedIndex = -1;
    CustomersName_ComBx.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

And the **SelectedIndexChanged** event as [Aleksandar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696562/2076880)

```
private void CustomersPhone_ComBx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedPhone = (string)CustomersPhone_ComBx.SelectedItem;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedPhone))
        CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Where(Customer => Customer.Phone == selectedPhone).Select(Customer => Customer.Name).ToList();
    else
        CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Name).ToList();
}
```

Comment: did you test both cases? `if (DeliveryPhone_ComBx.Text != "")` is the result the same in both?

Comment: How did you test it? did you set a breakpoint to check whether `CustomersPhone_ComBx_Leave`? is executed?

Comment: Yes, no difference. It still have the same DataSource whatever the situation. And if I add this line `CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = null;` before **if statement**, I find no items.

Comment: @MongZhu Yes, There's no problem with **if statement** at all.

Comment: are you sure you want it on leave and not on CustomersPhone_ComBx.selectedindexchanged?

Comment: Are you using standard WPF combobox, as far as i can see standard WPF combobox doesn't have DataSource property nor Leave event that corresponds that data being changed.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 that's not a big different, the result is no change happen !!

Comment: @Aleksandar I am using WinForms ComboBox

Comment: @Ctznkane525 ah, my bad i somehow missed winforms tag...

Comment: Hi, have you tried using a [BindingSource and/or BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603995/5174469) ? It is really an interesting issue thought. especially because it works with the loop. I still cannot reproduce your problem. Could you post code to fill `Customers` with values that generate the problem at your machine? so we can use to test it

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the property window of the combobox? we could compare with our working solution. Which .NET Version are you using?

Comment: @MongZhu, please see updates in post, and I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2, And **Yes**, I tried BindingSource and/or BindingList but the same !!

Comment: @ShadyBoshra finally I can reproduce your problem! this is a nice bug there that you have found. I write an answer. Hold on

Comment: now that is a problem I have never encountered before. Please try it out and tell me whether it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new information about the properties of the comboboxes I could finally reproduce your problem. It seems that the `Sorted` property is causing this problem:

```
this.CustomersName_ComBx.Sorted = true;
```

The solution is to set it to false

```
this.CustomersName_ComBx.Sorted = false;
```

to have the display still ordered, simply use `OrderBy` when you initialize the `DataSource`:

```
CustomersPhone_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Phone)
                                           .OrderBy(x=>x).Distinct().ToList();
CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource  = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Name)
                                           .OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

A (sort of explanation) can be found on the documentation of the property Sorted

In the Remarks section it says:

> This property specifies whether the ComboBox sorts existing entries and **add new entries** to the **appropriate sorted position** in the list. You can use this property to automatically sort items in a ComboBox. As items are added to a sorted ComboBox, the items are moved to the appropriate location in the sorted list.

I guess when you change the `DataSource` the new element are simply put at the positions of the old ones. But the actual `DataSource` has now less elements. You can check it in the debugger. The count of `DataSource` will be less after the filtered collection has been assigned!

My second guess would be that if you set `Sorted = true` it actually ignores the `DataSource` collection after the initial initialization and from this moment on it only displays what is in the `Items` collection. The debugger shows that `Items.Count` remains the same after the filtered `DataSource` has been assigned, but `DataSource.Count` has changed. This seems some sort of an ambiguous state. 
You cannot modify the `Items` collection because the `ComboBox` is data bound but you cannot display the `DataSource` because the `Sorted` is set to true. Actually the remarks say that:

> Attempting to set the Sorted property on a data-bound control raises an ArgumentException. You must sort the data using the underlying data model.

But it does not say what happens when you set it **before** the binding!

Comment: First: when I was using `Leave` event, sure it was fired because I focus on another ComboBox "Names".

Secode: I tried your code, and also nothing happen, the breakpoint stop on the code, but there's no difference in combobox items !!

Comment: @ShadyBoshra then I would need more information. can you post a sample of the content of customers?=! so that I can work with it. Up to now, I cannot reproduce your problem otherwise. I took 3 customers, 2 had the same number, and when I chose the double number only the 2 were left in the name combobox

Comment: Yes, this was the problem!! It works fine now, thanks. Can you explain why it was the problem ??

Comment: @ShadyBoshra I am trying. still putting the pieces together. Is the first version of my explanation understandable?

Comment: I commented before I see your full answer after you edited it. Now I understand all your answer. Thanks 

Comment: @ShadyBoshra you are very welcome. It was indeed an intriguing problem. Was fun to solve it. It shows once more, how much information one actually need to figure such stuff out. Cool that you have provided it ;-) cheers mate

Comment: @ShadyBoshra I have a second guess what it might be, if you're interested, have a look. Sounds may be more plausible. May be it is a little bit of both

Comment: What's your second guess ?

Comment: @ShadyBoshra see my edit: "if you set Sorted = true it actually ignores the DataSource collection after the initial initialization and from this moment on it only displays what is in the Items collection. ...."

Comment: Oh my bad sorry. I see now, and it may be your guess is right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that worked for me, only difference is that i've used CustomersPhone_ComBx.SelectedItem instead of its text property.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; } = new List<Customer>
    {
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "John",
            Phone = "123"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "Mary",
            Phone = "123"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "Peter",
            Phone = "555"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "George",
            Phone = "222"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "Christine",
            Phone = "555"
        }
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CustomersPhone_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Phone).ToList();
        CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Name).ToList();
    }

    private void CustomersPhone_ComBx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedPhone = (string) CustomersPhone_ComBx.SelectedItem;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedPhone))
            CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Where(Customer => Customer.Phone == selectedPhone).Select(Customer => Customer.Name).ToList();
        else
            CustomersName_ComBx.DataSource = Customers.Select(Customer => Customer.Name).ToList();
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me, and I don't know why !!, Please check theses screenshots

[Before change DataSource](https://imgur.com/a/0StLw)
----
[After change DataSource](https://imgur.com/a/NYj6Q)

Thanks

Comment: @ShadyBoshra Is the event wired up?  What happens when you put a debug stop on the first line of the event.

Comment: @LarsTech, I attached 2 screenshots for debug stop, before and after execution of line. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691615/combobox-datasource-dynamically-change/48696562?noredirect=1#comment84392053_48696562)

Comment: @ShadyBoshra Try setting datasource to null at the beginning of CustomersPhone_ComBx_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: @Aleksandar, Same problem, but now no item in ComboBox, check screenshots, [Before Exe. Line](https://imgur.com/a/Lhskx) -- [After Exe. Line](https://imgur.com/a/ZiPX2) !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11848691/2076880) but also nothing change !!

Comment: @ShadyBoshra according to screenshots DataSource is being set properly, maybe combobox isn't redrawing itself when you set DataSource ,try calling CustomersName_ComBx.Refresh();

Comment: @Aleksandar, I tried that too, nothing new, `this.refresh();` also didn't change anything :\ .. I googled it a lot, and it seems to be a bug -_-

Comment: @ShadyBoshra Do you mind sharing full source code of your form?